# Understanding the notion of i.i.d. in the Hilbert Space of Square-Integrable Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, hilbert-spaces, independence

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be square-integrable random variables in $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ with the usual inner product (and induced norm):
$$ \langle X, Y \rangle = \int XY \; d\mathbb{P}$$ I am tring to understand what it means for them to be independent and identically distributed from a "functional / inner product" perspective.  For simplicity, assume $\mathbb{E} X_i = \langle X_i, \mathbf{1}_\Omega \rangle = 0$ and $X_i \neq 0$ almost everywhere for each $i$.

If they are identically distributed, this means that the pushforward measure is the same for each $X_i$.  In other words, $\mathbb{P} \circ X^{-1}_i = \mathbb{P} \circ X^{-1}_j$, which I think in turn implies that $X_i = X_j$ almost everywhere.  Let's call the common function $X$.

However, if they are independent this implies that they have covariance $0$, i.e.
$$ \langle X_i, X_j \rangle = 0 $$
However, since each $X_i = X$ and $X_i \neq 0$ almost everywhere, this would seem to imply that
$$\langle X_i, X_j \rangle = \langle X, X \rangle = \lVert X \rVert^2 > 0 $$ which seems to be a contradiction.  Can someone clarify where my logic is going wrong?

Comment: Having the same pushforward does not imply $X_i = X_j$. It means $P(X_i \in B) = P(X_j \in B)$ for all $B$.

Comment: It wouldn't.  It would imply its $0$.  However, the "identically distributed" part seems to be implying the covariance is positive, which is obviously wrong.  So I'm trying to figure out where my mistake in reasoning is.

Comment: Your mistake is in misinterpreting what it means to be identically distributed, i.e. as taking it to mean equality almost surely.

Comment: if you are interested in a functional analysis perspective, such a program is carried out in Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability, especially in the chapter on conditional probability.

Comment: Thanks! Yes that just might be it.  Can you tell me if this reasoning is sound?  Fix some measurable set $S$. What you're saying is that $X_i^{-1}$ and $X_j^{-1}$ send $S$ to different parts of $\Omega$.  However, the images of these maps still have the same measure.

Comment: Thank you for the reference; I will investigate it.  I am currently using Bobrowski's Functional Analaysis for Probability and Stochastic Processes.  If you have familiarity with this text, do you recommend it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly not true that $\ \mathbb{P}\circ X_i^{-1}=\ \mathbb{P}\circ X_j^{-1}\ $ implies that $\ X_i=X_j\ $ almost everywhere.  To take a simple counterexample, let $\ \Omega=\mathbb{R}^2\ $, $\ \mathcal{F}\ $ be the Borel subsets of $\ \Omega\ $,
$$
\mathbb{P}(A)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_A e^{-\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2}{2}}dx_1dx_ 2
$$
for $\ A\in\mathcal{F}\ ,$ and
$$
X_1\big(x_1,x_2\big)=x_1\ ,\\
X_2\big(x_1,x_2\big)=x_2\ \ 
$$
for $\ \big(x_1,x_2\big)\in\Omega\ $.  Then $\ X_1,X_2\ $ are independent, identically distributed random variables in $\ L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})\ $ (their common distribution is the [standard normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution)), but
$$
\left\{\big(x_1,x_2\big)\in\Omega\,\big|\,X_1\big(x_1,x_2\big)=X_2\big(x_1,x_2\big)\right\}=\left\{\big(x_1,x_2\big)\in\Omega\,\big|\,x_1=x_2\right\}\ ,
$$
which has probability $\ 0\ $.

Comment: In light of your construction, can I ask if the following line of reasoning tracks (being a little flippant with language).  If I want to consider a bunch of $n$ i.i.d. variables, I can first take overall measure space to be the product of $n$ simpler measure spaces.  Then I can define some $X$ that maps this space into $\mathbb{R}^n$.  And then I define each $X_i$ as a projection onto the $i$-th coordinate.  Does that work?

Comment: Yes.  In fact that's typically the normal way it's done.  If $\ \mathbb{F}\ $ is the common distribution (on $\ \mathbb{R}\ $) of the $\ X_i\ $ then you can define the probability $\ \mathbb{P}\ $ as
$$
\mathbb{P}\big(A_1\times A_2\times\dots\times A_n\big)=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{F}\big(A_i\big)
$$
on products of Borel sets $\ A_1,A_2 \dots, A_n\ $ of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $, and standard results of measure theory guarantee that this can be extended uniquely to a probability measure on the Borel sets of $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $.

Answer (score 2):

Being identically distributed does not imply being equal a.e. For example, in one dimension you can have a positive, triangle-shaped r.v. $X$ and a positive r.v. whose graph consists of two triangles $Y$ with half the base and the same height in such a way that the sets $\{x:X\ge \alpha\}$ and $\{x:Y\ge \alpha\}$ have the same total length for every $\alpha>0$.

Comment: Just to clarify that I understand this counterexample.  I took $\Omega = [0,1]$ and set $X_1$ and $X_2$ to be the triangle function maps you laid out with a height of 1.  If I take the pre-image of lets say $(1-\epsilon, 1]$ for each $X_i$ these point to 2 different sets, the first a ball around 0.5 and the second is the union of 2 balls centered around 0.25 and 0.75, respectively.  The Lebesgue / standard uniform measure of each set is the same, which was your point.  However, what if the underlying measure $\mathbb{P}$ was not standard uniform? Does this example still work?

Comment: This example would not work, it would have to be modified. But this example clearly shows that the implication "identically distributed" => "equal a.e." is false.